# Beautiful Soup object's HTML, does not match HTML from the web browser

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am scraping the links from this website https://www.firstmallorca.com/en/search, for each of the properties that appear on it, so I can further scrape them and collect more detailed data.

My problem is that the parsed HTML(I am using html5lib parser) from which I scrape the data seems to be different in some areas with respect to the HTML which I see on the browser's DevTool. To demonstrate this:

1.This is the last link I select. On the browser, its href="/en/sales/penthouse-in-santa-ponsa/102512"
[1.Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOE1N.png)

2.I print the parsed HTML from the Beautiful Soup Object from the webpage with bs4Object.prettfy() and I copy the whole output into notepad++.

3.Then, in the notepad I look for the same element as in point 1. I find it and the href="/en/sales/finca-in-portocolom/159515", which is different from what I see on the actual webpage.[3.Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRQnw.png)

I do not understand the nature of what's happening. On point 3, I was expecting to see href="/en/sales/penthouse-in-santa-ponsa/102512" instead of href="/en/sales/finca-in-portocolom/159515".

It seems to me like I am doing the scraping on other similar webpage, though not the one I see through the browser.

Answer (score 0):

The website loads content via javascript, which your parser does not execute.

This is a task for [selenium](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/).

> The selenium package is used to automate the interaction with the web browser from Python.